# Fancybox creating error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, syntax-error, fancybox

I have two pages, both of which are using the fancybox jquery lib. One page works, with no errors. The other page (which has identical (I think) syntax) is producing an error. This **only** occurs in Chrome.

Here is the working code:

```
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'type'          : 'inline',
            'minWidth'      : 920,
            'minHeight'     : 700,
            'width'         : '90%',
            'height'        : '90%',
            'autosize'      : false,
            'fitToView'     : true,
            'margin'        : 15,
            'padding'       : 5,
            'closeEffect'   : 'fade'
        });
```

and the failing code:

```
        $(document).ready(function({
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'type'      : 'inline',
            'autosize'  : false,
            'width'     : 50,
            'height'    : 100,
            'margin'    : 10,
            'padding'   : [25,25,300,0]
        });
    });
```

The error coming up in the Chrome console is:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string**

The line of code that is underlined with the problem is: *$('.fancybox').fancybox({*

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not the the Fancy box, but in `$(document).ready(function({...}))`. You forgot the closing bracket in `.ready()` function after arguments.

Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        'type'      : 'inline',
        'autosize'  : false,
        'width'     : 50,
        'height'    : 100,
        'margin'    : 10,
        'padding'   : [25,25,300,0]
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch... I looked and looked and never saw the syntax error! Thank you so much.

Comment: He didn't forgot the closing bracket. The actual error was here `(document).ready(function({...`, which should be `(document).ready(function(){...` ... in case someone wants to know what the actual syntax error was